# Matlab multi-start with lsqnonlin

Tags: matlab, solver

I have to following code:

```
lb=[-10,16,-3,-10,2,8,-10,-7,-3,-10,2,-13,-20,-20,-20,-20];     %lower Bound            
ub=[-5,20,3,-5,8,15,-5,-3,3,-5,8,-8,20,20,20,20];               %upper Bound    
x0 = [-8.4,18,0,-9,5,11,-9,-6,0,-9,5,-11,10,-12,11,-11];                %Startwerte 

f_schnittgeraden=...
    @(x)f_root2d_schnittgeraden(x,stzpkt,w,Kantenlaenge,Winkel);

[x,res] = lsqnonlin(f_schnittgeraden,x0,lb,ub);
```

with f_root2d_schnittgeraden:

```
function F = f_root2d_schnittgeraden(x,stzpkt,w,Kantenlaenge,Winkel)

%Schnittgerade 1
F(1) = stzpkt(1,1) + x(13)*w(1,1)-x(1); %x13 ist dieser Parameter vor dem Richtungsvektor. Dieser ist für eine Gerade immer gleich
F(2) = stzpkt(2,1) + x(13)*w(2,1)-x(2);
F(3) = stzpkt(3,1) + x(13)*w(3,1)-x(3);
%Schnittgerade 2
F(4) = stzpkt(1,2) + x(14)*w(1,2)-x(4); %x14 ist dieser Parameter von dem Richtungsvektor
F(5) = stzpkt(2,2) + x(14)*w(2,2)-x(5);
F(6) = stzpkt(3,2) + x(14)*w(3,2)-x(6);
...
F(12)=...
end
```

I want to implement the Multistart with lsqnonlin in Matlab. what changes need to be made?

Comment: This question could possibly be, slightly, convoluted. Adding a link to the documentation of isqnonlin could be a helpful start to help people answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out the following

```
[x,res] = lsqnonlin(f_schnittgeraden,x0,lb,ub);
```

And add the following

```
rng default                  % For reproducibility
opts = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective');
problem = createOptimProblem('lsqnonlin','objective',...
    f_schnittgeraden,'x0',x0,'lb',lb,'ub',ub,'options',opts);
ms = MultiStart;
[x,f] = run(ms,problem,20)
```

Note, **trust-region-reflective** option is required.

This configuration will perform 20 multistarts.